# Organizing AWS Lambda functions for multiple projects and environments

Tags: aws-lambda

I am just getting started with AWS Lambdas so for my first project i created about 15 that i needed to get up and running. When i go to the AWS Lambda management console under the Functions tab there they all are staring back at me. 
That is all well and good but that was just for the dev environment of this project. I will have 3 other environments with the same 15 functions.
And at some point i'm going to have other projects, other functions, other environments. I don't want to have to sift through this giant list to get access and manipulate these functions. There has to be a better way to organize these.
I don't want to name every function as *project_function_environment*. that seems silly to me. Is there a better way?

Can i make folders or use tags?

Could i use a different aws role or some other aws construct?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing large projects, you definitely don't want to be managing everything from the Lambda website interface. There are all sorts of CI tools to help automatically setup and deploy your code. Many will integrate with services like github which allows you to start the deploy process by just pushing new code. AWS has Code Pipeline, which is designed to help these kind of difficulties. There's generally a lot of upfront setup followed by small payoffs every time you deploy new code. Here's a decent article about making a bridge between github and lambda deployment:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

Comment: yep. thanks for the tip. but these are just small projects with a team of one.